# Restart a non-void function

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have the following code:

```
- (NSString*)returnIncorrectDef {
NSInteger defIndex = [self randomIndex];

NSString *incorrectDef = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [definitions objectAtIndex:defIndex]];

if (([incorrectDef isEqualToString:self.definitionString]) || ([incorrectDef isEqualToString:def1.titleLabel.text])) {
    // I want to restart the method here
    [self returnIncorrectDef];
} else {
    return incorrectDef;
}}
```

I want to be able to restart this method until the if clause is not met. However when I try this code I get an error saying: "Control may reach end of non-void function". How would I do this?

Comment: Define "restart".  What you have is a recursive call, but it fails to return the result, hence the error message.  You could just add a `return` ahead of `[self returnIncorrectDef];`, but you run the risk of "infinite" recursion.  It would make more sense to just surround the whole loop body with a loop that only exits when your exit conditions are met.

Comment: (Though the loop approach will almost certainly result in an "infinite loop".  But at least it won't crash.)

Comment: ...but the app will be irresponsive and 'hang' (if this is in any way better than a crash). So insert some sanity checks in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `while` loop with a flag:

```
- (NSString*)returnIncorrectDef {
    BOOL done = NO;
    NSString *incorrectDef = nil;
    while (!done) {
        NSInteger defIndex = [self randomIndex];
        incorrectDef = [definitions objectAtIndex:defIndex];
        done = !([incorrectDef isEqualToString:self.definitionString] ||
                 [incorrectDef isEqualToString:def1.titleLabel.text]);
    }
    return incorrectDef;
}
```

You can also use `do ... while` statement.

<strike>Note that `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",...]` is a pointless statement and has been simplified.</strike> (see @medvedNick's comment - it's not pointless if that class isn't an `NSString` class).

**IMPORTANT**: Without the `while` loop, you are using recursion, which could potentially crash your program if you keep "missing" your target (which is certainly possible).

Comment: if `definitions` is not `NSString` array (and we can not say it is), the `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",...]` is not so pointless

Comment: It should be pointed out that the definition of `definitions` is not available, and unless it's (at the very least) `volatile` an infinite loop is almost guaranteed.

Comment: @HotLicks Why do you say that?  Surely it depends on what `[self randomIndex]` returns?

Comment: @medvedNick Yes, but if `definitions` is not an `NSString` then the code would rely on the `description`
 method which is is just intended to be a human-readable string with information about the object, not something to be used as actual data in production code.

Comment: @trojanfoe - Yeah, I guess I missed that.  Though neither match is assured, in any sort of general case.

Comment: @Monolo Yeah that's true.  I'm like one of those people at the moment who agrees with whatever the last person just said.  I should have thought it through more.

Answer (score 2):

trojanfoe's solution is better, but the issue you have is that you never return the value that you get  when you reenter.  CHanging that line to

```
return [self returnIncorrectDef];
```

should fix the problem

Comment: The best reason to suggest my solution is that it is the minimum change required to solve the error he is getting, so it does a good job of demonstrating WHY the compiler cared about the error in the first place (so that he can find it the next time it occurs).  Your solution, with iteration, is a much more efficient, easier to read, and cleaner solution, but it requires rewriting logic, obscuring the error he had in the first place.

Comment: Except that the above "solution" will likely lead to a mysterious crash that will totally befuddle the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[self returnIncorrectDef];` simply do:
`return [self returnIncorrectDef];`

That way you return a value by recursively calling your function. Be sure that the evaluation parameters change though, to prevent an infinite loop

**EDIT** but this might not be what you want in this particular case (calling the method over and over again)

Comment: In principle recursive functions can be useful. It depends on what is actually expected in the code. But that's the answer to the question about 'restarting a function'

Comment: And they don't have *any* downsides?

Comment: What do you think the downside is?

Comment: Stackoverflow if the function keeps recursing, and given that is based on a random value, will happen at some point.

Comment: The downside would be a mysterious crash that would totally befuddle the poor OP.

Comment: Sure. But what prevents your while loop from being an infinite loop (not crashing but 'hanging' the app) if the condition is never met. The code depends a bit on implementation of other methods (that e don't get to see here). You DO have to apply some sort of sanity checks either way

Comment: It won't cause a crash though.  Plus it will be much quicker.

Comment: I give you that in this case, I wouldn't use recursion either - your answer is better for that particular implementation of the method... No discussion here